# In operator in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, notin, in-operator

There is several items in drop-down i.e.

```
Apply
Orange
Grapes
Factory
```

I try to fill drop down with two linq queries like this

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            if (Session["UserName"] == "admin")
            {
                //List<spadminlist_Result> admin = tea.spadminlist().ToList();

                var admin=from ad in tea.tblReg
                          .Where((x=>x.Region).Contains("Factory"))
                          .GroupBy(x=>x.Region)
                          .Select(x=> new {Region=x.Key})
                          .ToList();



                regiondrop.DataSource = admin;
                regiondrop.DataTextField = "Region";
                regiondrop.DataValueField = "Region";
                regiondrop.DataBind();
                Label4.Visible = false;

            }
            else
            {
                var list = tea.tblReg.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(x => !x.Region.Any(char.IsDigit) && (x.Region != ""))
                   .GroupBy(x => x.Region)
                   .Select(x => new { Region = x.Key, Value = x.Key })
                   .ToList();

                regiondrop.DataSource = list;
                regiondrop.DataTextField = "Region";
                regiondrop.DataValueField = "Region";
                regiondrop.DataBind();
                Label4.Visible = false;
            }

        }
```

now when i try this line 
//List admin = tea.spadminlist().ToList();
then datasource show null 
where as sp return values ie. Factory

so i decide to qrite linq query so after write linq query this

```
var admin=from ad in tea.tblReg
                          .Where((x=>x.Region).Contains("Factory"))
                          .GroupBy(x=>x.Region)
                          .Select(x=> new {Region=x.Key})
                          .ToList();
```

this shows an error

> Error 3   A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

and also i want if role is not admin then i dont want to display Factory value and if the role is admin then only i want to display value "Factory" in dropdown 
so how i use not in operator in 2nd linq query and for in operator i use contains operator in 1st LINQ but this show an error as i above mentioned

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: want to achieve when admin login then only display Factory value in dropdown otherwise all values will be display in dropdown ..

Comment: please edit the name of the question to better fit the problem + if you may remove the comments from the question bellow - they do not add useful information for future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your `Where` is wrong and you don't need to `GroupBy`.

```
var admin = tea.tblReg.Where(x => x.Region == "Factory")
                      .Select(x => x.Region)
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToList();
```

This will retrieve from database only the record where `Region` is "Factory" and will created it in the same form like in the `else`

---

You can also refactor a bit your code to reduce the repetition (and more can still be done):

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (Session["UserName"] == "admin")
    {
        regiondrop.DataSource = tea.tblReg.Where(x => x.Region == "Factory")
                                   .Select(x => x.Region)
                                   .Distinct()
                                   .ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        regiondrop.DataSource = tea.tblReg.Where(x => x.Region.All(char.IsLetter) && 
                                                      x.Region != "" &&
                                                      x.Region != "Factory")
                                          .Select(x => x.Region)
                                          .Distinct()
                                          .ToList();
    }

    regiondrop.DataTextField = "Region";
    regiondrop.DataValueField = "Region";
    regiondrop.DataBind();
    Label4.Visible = false;
}
```

*Notice also that I changed the use of `!Any(char.IsDigit)` to `All(char.IsLetter)` - a clearer way of doing so*

Comment: this show an error on 1st linq query.. Error 4 'chart_project.tblReg' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'chart_project.tblReg' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: and what if i dont want Factory value in 2nd linq query how i dot that also

Comment: for not want Factory i do this...                        .Where(x => !x.Region.Any(char.IsDigit)  && (x.Region != "") && (x => !exceptionList.Contains("Factory"))) 
but this show an error..  Error 5 A local variable named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'x', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: @ Gilad Green but there is also several numbers in Region column and i dont want that thats why i put this  !Any(char.IsDigit)

Comment: @user6628729 - See latest edit. Added that value isn't "Factory" and removed the GroupBy also from this query. I strongly recommend that you look into lambda expressions and linq

Comment: yes i am trying .. and this show warning on   if (Session["UserName"] == "admin")  .. Warning 3 Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Comment: ok i tried that and 1st linq query show null on datasource .. and on 2nd linq query show 13 count  :/

Comment: @user6628729 - please focus to the scope of your question - which was how to get only the "Factory" value from the database (which then you also added how to get all except that one)

Comment: @user6628729 - please move to chat - this is making comments really messy